# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when

Tags: python, api

I am trying to collect data from a paginated API and for some reason I cannot find a workaround for the *'NoneType' object is not iterable TypeError*. Please see code below.

```
import json 
import requests
import fsspec
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

parameters = {
    "CreatedAfterUTC": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
    "PageNum": 1,
    "RecordsPerPage": 2000
}

headers = {
"Content-Type" : "application/json",
"Authorization": str('APIKEY'),
}

referrals = []

pagenum = 1

while True:
    url = f"https://restapi.erelocation.net/api/v1/GetReferrals?PageNum={pagenum}&RecordsPerPage=2000"
    print("Requesting", url)
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=parameters)
    data = resp.json()
    for item in data.get('Referral', []):
        if len(data['Referral']) == 0:
            break
    referrals.extend(data['Referral'])
    pagenum = pagenum + 1
```

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**

Comment: Please **always post the complete error message including the stack trace**. The Python runtime goes to great lengths to provide critical debugging information to you, why would you just *leave that out*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am still new to coding and Stack Overflow so apologies if the post is incomplete. I do not follow, what is the solution to the problem?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see what you are saying now. For some reason, even with `data.get('Referral', [])` I still get the same error. Here is what occurred during [my latest run-through](https://imgur.com/a/Vam8oiY)

Comment: Please post the error message in the question itself as formatted text, do not post links to error messages, or images of error messages. All of this should be in the question. Please see [ask] and the [help], since you are new here

Comment: It seems that sometimes the `"Referral"` value is `None`. You can just do something like `referral = [] if not data.get("Referral") else data.get("Referral")` then just use `referral`